# Filter duplicate rows in mysql by using customer id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

### customer table

It has 3 fields..

1. customer_id
2. first_name
3. last_name

### customer address table

It has 2 fields

1. customer_id
2. address

My problem is my customer table has 259 rows where as my customer address table has 400+ rows.
I mean my customer address table contains duplicate rows.

Now i would like select only unique rows from my customer address table...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the event that the `customer_id` and `address` are the same for each duplicate, you could use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`customer_id`), `address` FROM `customer_addresses`;
```

If a customer has two different addresses in the table, you will receive two results with the above query. To get a single result per customer, you can use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT `customer_id`, `address` FROM `customer_addresses` GROUP BY `customer_id`;
```

This will be guaranteed to return a single result per-customer.

To build upon the use of `GROUP BY`, you can also use it to *find* the customers with duplicate entries:

```
SELECT `customer_id` FROM `customer_addresses` GROUP BY `customer_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This will return only the customer's that have duplicate entries (i.e. - a count of >1) in the `customer_addresses` table - which may help you resolve your duplicate problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `DISTINCT` keyword to your SQL statement.

**Reference:** http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php